# Recalculate connection points

Tags: javascript, gojs

I'm using custom the 'points' binding to generate custom linepoints. The beginning and the ending of the point always starts at the topleft of a node.

Is it posibble to recalculate the line by GoJS, so the position will not be topleft, but to the closest point instead (i.e. BR to BL on the given example)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting

```
// Used as a value for {@link Link#adjusting},
// to indicate that the link route computation should keep the
// intermediate points of the previous route, just modifying the first and/or last points;
theLink.adjusting = go.Link.End;
```

And then recalculating the link route.

```
theLink.invalidateRoute();
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to affect anything. See: http://jsfiddle.net/rb7nyxfd/45/

Comment: I added a transaction after the model setter to force the state to finish before calling the link change: http://jsfiddle.net/rb7nyxfd/46/